# Dictionary from excell Columns Python

Tags: python

Given an excell who can have 1 or multiple colums:

Cars          Colors
Audi          yellow
Mazda         blue
Toyota        red

Create a dictionary that has as its key the first element from the column and as value a list with the rest of the elements and its returned on output:

```
{'Cars':['Audi','Mazda','Toyota'],
  Colors':['yellow','blue','red']}
```

What I came up with is just a list with all the clumns/rows appended, i don't know how to make it as a dictionary from the start.

```
 def readExcelData():
    tempDict = defaultdict(dict)
    tag_rowlst = []

    from openpyxl import load_workbook
    book = load_workbook(pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__, 'input_data.xlsx'))
    sheet = book['Sheet1']

    print(sheet.max_column)
    for j in range(0, sheet.max_column):
        for row in sheet.rows:
            if type(row[j].value) is str:
                tag_rowlst.append(row[j].value)
                #print(type(row[1].value))

    print(tag_rowlst)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easier with pandas..

```
n [63]: df = pd.read_excel("a.xlsx")

In [64]: df
Out[64]:
     Cars  Colors
0    Audi  yellow
1   Mazda    blue
2  Toyota     red

In [73]: {col:list(df[col]) for col in df.columns}
Out[73]: {'Cars': ['Audi', 'Mazda', 'Toyota'], 'Colors': ['yellow', 'blue', 'red']}
```

To not print `NaNs`

```
In [130]: df = pd.read_excel("a.xlsx")

In [131]: df
Out[131]:
     Cars  Colors
0    Audi  yellow
1   Mazda    blue
2  Toyota     NaN

In [132]: {col:list(df[df[col].notnull()][col]) for col in df.columns}
Out[132]: {'Cars': ['Audi', 'Mazda', 'Toyota'], 'Colors': ['yellow', 'blue']}
```

Comment: Yeah this worked like charm, is there a way to remove nan type elements when the columns are irregular? like colors column has just 1 color, it autofills the list with something called 'nan' thaat is float as type.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('your excel file path')
dict = df.to_dict(list)
```

this will give you your dictionary

Comment: Very clean and efficient, but this will give you: {'Cars': {0: 'Audi', 1: 'Mazda', 2: 'Toyota'},
 'Colors': {0: 'yellow', 1: 'blue', 2: 'red'}} which is not yet the desired output.

Comment: use `df.to_dict('list')` to get exact dict without index.

Comment: df.to_dict(orient="list")

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r"test.xlsx")
your_dict = {col:lst for (col, lst) in zip(df.columns, df.T.values.tolist())}
```

You can use dictionary comprehension combined with a transposed datafrme which is available via: df.T